# how to sum only hours from datetime field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to sum the hours from a `datetime` column in a sql but I am getting an error when I try this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(HH, SUM(DATEDIFF(HH, '00:00:00.000', myDate)), '00:00:00.000') as Total_Hours 
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID in (1, 2)
```

My date column looks like this

```
2015-02-18 00:00:00.000
2015-02-18 00:30:00.000
2015-02-18 01:00:00.000
2015-02-18 01:30:00.000
```

How can I sum and only show the total hours with out the date?

Comment: What result do you want from the sample data?

Comment: if i add these 2 datetime: 2015-02-18 00:00:00.000
2015-02-18 00:30:00.000 i should get 30 min as total hours

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to extract the hours and add them up?  The conversion back to a data is definitely unnecessary:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEPART(hour, myDate)) as Total_Hours
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID in (1, 2);
```

EDIT;

If you want to add the time component, then use minutes or seconds:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEPART(second, myDate)) / (60.0 * 60.0) as Total_Hours
FROM myTable 
WHERE ID in (1, 2);
```

Comment: if you add the first 2, it should give you 30 min but in your query it gives me 0

Comment: @moe . . . Then you don't want to add hours.

Comment: thanks Gordon, but i am getting 0.0000.  the datetime field is 30 minute interval so for example, 1:00, 1:30, 2:00, 2:30 etc.  so if i add from 1:00 to 1:30 then i should get 30 minutes right?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression that you want to add the time parts together:

```
select Total_Hours = datepart(hour, cast(myDate as time))
from myTable
where id in (1, 2)
```

Comment: Yes Ako but i don't see where you sum up here the total hours here

Comment: Added it, but in your example this will be 0, because hours in '00:30:00' is 0.

Comment: i am confused here please help me out here, in my example there are 4 entries so if i add all these hours and that is 12:00 am to 1:30 so i expect to see total hours =1.30.  I am basically trying to add up all the hours/minutes. thanks

Comment: Your sql example says where id in (1, 2) , so I thought that you select only first two rows.